# Actually finding a $W^\prime$ s.t $W\oplus W^\prime =V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\mathbb R_4[x]$ be the space of polynomials of degree no greater than four. Let $W=\operatorname{span} \left\{x^4-x^2,3x^4-x^3+1 \right\}$. I want to find a subspace $W^\prime$ such that $W\oplus W^\prime =V$. I think the key is to write some equations down which represent the uniqueness of representation of any element of $V=\mathbb R_r[x]$, but I just don't know which equations to write. Whatever I do I'm stuck with too many variables!

Comment: Begin with a basis for $W$, then extend it to a basis for $V$.  The span of the added basis elements is $W'$.

Comment: @GEdgar I think adding $1,x,x^2$ works here, right?

Comment: Once you have the candidate, prove it.  You know how to compute whether a set of vectors in linearly independent?

Comment: @GEdgar I did check linear independence and got a good answer, I just wanted to make sure with you! (I found that adding $1,x,x^2$ works.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do it in a tricky way. You can represent $x^4-x^2$ as $(0,0,-1,0,1)$ and $3x^4-x^3+1$ as $(1,0,0,-1,3)$. Then you get the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&-1&0&1\\1&0&0&-1&3\end{pmatrix}.$$
Try to complete to do an invertible matrix. So something like
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&-1&0&1\\1&0&0&-1&3\\ 0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$
(you construct the matrix to finally have a simple determinant to compute at the end).

Therefore, $\{x^4-x^2,1-x^3+3x^4,x^2,x,1\}$ worsk. I don't know how deep is you knowledge in linear algebra, but there is no general way to construct a basis, and this way is very quick and easy if you know the determinant.